# iTunes keyboard shortcuts: should Windows alternatives be listed?

Tags: discussion

I often give keyboard shortcuts in my answers. Usually, this is for Mac software, so I can just say "Use <kbd>⌘ (cmd)</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to select all," but when I'm giving instructions for iTunes shortcuts, I have no way of knowing the OS the asker is running unless they explicitly state it. When they don't, what should I use? "⌘ (cmd, or ctrl if you're running Windows)"?

(Also, please don't tell me to just give the menu path. I usually give shortcuts in conjunction with those.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's OK to assume the asker is using Mac OS unless they explicitly specify otherwise in the title, body, or tags of their question (best to check all 3).

Comment: Perhaps we could add something to the FAQ about that -- "Questions about Apple software running on Microsoft Windows are on topic, but please specify that in your question, as answerers here are otherwise apt to assume you are using a Mac."

Comment: @Daniel unfortunately we can only edit the top section of the FAQ ("what kinds of questions can I ask here?"). maybe tag wiki edits world work?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the Apple shortcuts.  The assumption if nothing is stated has to be that the user is on a Mac.  Doing a tag search yields the following stats for results this year to date:

[itunes] [windows] - 2 hits

[itunes] [os x] - 2 hits

[itunes] [mac] - 4 hits

[itunes] - 100+ hits

So by some very basic maths (with the obvious problem that some of the [itunes] only search results were also for [ios]/[ipad]/[iphone]/[ipod] etc etc where shortcuts are not appropriate anyway) would suggest less than 2% of questions explicitly state Windows.

Comment: Thanks, though on questions that *do* state "windows", it isn't really an issue. It's only on the ones that don't say either way that it comes up.